# Solve $x^2 \frac{d^2y}{dx^2}+4x \frac{dy}{dx} + 2y= \cos x$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Solve $$x^2 \frac{d^2y}{dx^2}+4x \frac{dy}{dx} + 2y= \cos x$$

My attempt: Let $x=e^u$, and $D=\frac{d}{du}$ then the given equation becomes $$(D+2)(D+1)y=\cos(e^u)$$

Solving the corresponding homogeneous equation, taking $y=e^{mx}$,

I got $m=-1,-2$, so the C.F. is $$y_c=c_1e^{-u}+c_2e^{-2u}$$

My trouble is with finding the particular integral.

$y_p=\dfrac{\cos(e^u)}{(D+1)(D+2)}$

Now, I can break the denominator part like this: 
$$\dfrac{1}{(D+1)(D+2)}=\dfrac{(1+D)^{-1}(1+\frac D2)^{-1}}{2}=\dfrac{(1-D)(1-\frac D2)}{2}$$

Now, $D(\cos(e^u))=-e^u\sin(e^u)$,

So $$y_p=\dfrac{\cos(e^u)}{(D+1)(D+2)}=\dfrac{(1-D)(1-\frac D2)(\cos(e^u))}{2}$$

gives me $$y_p=\dfrac{\cos(e^u)+e^u\sin(e^u)-\frac{e^{2u}\sin(e^u)}{2}}{2}$$

But I am supposed to get just:  $$y_p=-e^{-2u}\cos(e^u)$$

Can somebody please explain what I'm doing wrong? Thank you!

Comment: but the coefficients are not constant, solutions are $$1/x$$ and $$1/x^2$$

Comment: Who teaches solving differential equations like this?!

Comment: @Chappers This is how we did in class. But I also know the short-cut method formulas given in the books.

Comment: I don't see how you "break the denominator part". Why should that be true?

Comment: @mickep I meant break as in rewrite, taking the terms to the numerator and expanding them by binomial theorem. Sorry, I should have been more precise!

Comment: Then I don't see why you get what you get, is it some commutation relations for these kind of functions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint**
$$(x^2y)''=(x^2y'+2xy)'=x^2y''+4xy'+2y$$

Answer (score 1):

You're wrong regarding your Complementary function; here youre trying the ansatz y=exp(mx)... The homog. part of this problem is one of Euler-Cauchy form.... I.e. you should be trying y=x^n .... dy/dx= n x^(n-1) .... dy^2/dx^2 =n(n-1)x^(n-2)... sub in to the LHS=0 , divide both sides by x^n, and you're left with a quadratic for which two n you need, your C.F. side will be of the form y=a x^(n1)+bx^(n2) , where n1 and n2 are the roots of the quadratic from your substitution... Your particular integral , one of trig form, is rather simple... so I'll leave that for you to do.

Comment: Just to maybe make this simpler , for your complementary function, you tried y=e^(mx) ... but this only works when you have real numbers in front of y'', y' and y. So, since you have x^2 , x's you try y= x^n.... sub this in and you'll see why it works. The roots for your quadratic in n , n1 and n2 ,will go in to y_ (c.f)= a x^(n1) +b x^(n2).... Then find your P.I and you're done.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%E2%80%93Euler_equation

Answer (score 0):

I think this method is a bit strange, and I'm not familiar with it so well that I can say what is going wrong. The only thing I see is the point I mentioned in the comment.

However, let me try to make sense of
$$
(D+1)^{-1}(D+2)^{-1}\cos(e^u).
$$
*You* make this rigorous.

First, we note that
$$
\begin{aligned}
(D+a)\cos(e^u)&=-e^u\sin(e^u)+a\cos(e^u),\quad\text{and}\\
(D+b)\sin(e^u)&=e^u\cos(e^u)+b\sin(e^u)
\end{aligned}
$$
Thus
$$
\begin{aligned}
\cos(e^u)&=(D+a)^{-1}\bigl[-e^u\sin(e^u)+a\cos(e^u)\bigr]\qquad(*)\\
&=-e^u(D+a+1)^{-1}\sin(e^u)+a(D+a)^{-1}\cos(e^u)
\end{aligned}
$$
and
$$
\begin{split}
\sin(e^u)&=(D+b)^{-1}\bigl[e^u\cos(e^u)+b\sin(e^u)\bigr]\qquad(**)\\
&=e^u(D+b+1)^{-1}\cos(e^u)+b(D+b)^{-1}\sin(e^u).
\end{split}
$$
We find that
$$
\begin{split}
(D+2)^{-1}\cos(e^u)&\stackrel{(**)}{=}e^{-u}\sin(e^u)-e^{-u}(D+1)^{-1}\sin(e^u)\\
&\stackrel{(*)}{=}e^{-u}\sin(e^u)+e^{-2u}\cos(e^u)
\end{split}
$$
Applying $(D+1)^{-1}$, and using $(D+c)^{-1}e^{dx}=e^{dx}(D+c+d)^{-1}$,
$$
\begin{split}
(D+1)^{-1}(D+2)^{-1}\cos(e^u)&=(D+1)^{-1}e^{-u}\sin(e^u)+(D+1)^{-1}e^{-2u}\cos(e^u)\\
&=e^{-u}D^{-1}\sin(e^u)+e^{-2u}(D-1)^{-1}\cos(e^u)\qquad{(***)}
\end{split}
$$
Now, by $(*)$ with $a=-1$,
$$
e^{-u}D^{-1}\sin(e^u)=-e^{-2u}\cos(e^u)-e^{-2u}(D-1)^{-1}\cos(e^u).
$$
If we insert this in $(***)$, we find that one term cancels, and we are left with

> $$
> (D+1)^{-1}(D+2)^{-1}\cos(e^u)=-e^{-2u}\cos(e^u).
> $$

In the end, this means that the general solution to the original differential equation is
$$
y(x)=\frac{c_1}{x}+\frac{c_2}{x^2}-\frac{\cos x}{x^2},
$$
which of course could have been found with simpler methods, or by just recognizing the second derivative of $x^2y$, as in the answer by @n-s.